# Clion using Cygwin is not passing arguments to main in Debug mode on Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, argv, clion

If I run the program without the debugger attaching all of the arguments get passed correctly, but if I run with the debugger attaching none of the arguments get passed in.

The installed toolchains are:

- Cygwin 2.7.0
- Cygwin GDB 7.11.1-2
- CMake 3.6.2

Is there a flag I need to pass to GCC to accept program arguments?

[image: Clion Target Configuration]

Comment: What is the CLion version you use?

Comment: I'm using CLion 2016.3.4

Comment: TBH I couldn't reproduce the issue, neither with 2016.3.4 nor with the current nightly, tried with Cygwin 2.6.0 and 2.7.0. Does the issue reproduce on a simple "hello world" example?

Comment: Let me try.  I'll also go ahead and try with a clean Cygwin install, as well.

Comment: Yeah, the issue doesn't happen with a new project started on Windows.

Comment: Alright, found the bug. One of the file names I'm passing in has an umlaut above the a. That causes everything to get messed up. It causes problems in a batch file for sure. I don't know if this is a CLion bug or Windows bug.

Comment: Unicode chars in program arguments indeed cause problems on Windows, thank you for reporting!